# Sublime Text 2 -- create new file in sidebar

Tags: sublimetext2

I've been playing with with sublime text 2, and it's great. When I first installed it however, when I right clicked in the "library" panel in the sidebar and selected new file it prompted me to name and save the file.

Now after installing emmett and a few other plugins (and registering the product!) it simply opens a new blank document, which requires extra steps to save and doesn't detect the code properly until it's saved with the proper file extension.

What did I do wrong?

Plugins installed: 
Emmett, 
RubyTest, 
Package Control

Basically I want to get back the default functionality, where you right click in the left panel (file directory view) and when you select New File it prompts for the filename rather than opening a blank document.

Comment: Perhaps you can give bit more detail on what you want it to do and what plugins you've installed

Comment: Were you using https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements?

Comment: @skuroda-- I may have installed that one. Is it possible to back it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the sublime package SideBarEnhancements from the package controller: install package.